# SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged not getting HDMI Arrival/Removal event?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10-desktop, systemevent

I am trying to track a HDMI monitor connection/removal using the below code. That `DisplaySettingChanged` event is however not triggered for most of the monitors. A HDMI monitor removal event is not raised most of the times.

Event registration:

```
 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
```

Method:

```
private static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Display settings changed.");
}
```

For example, using an **Acer S240HL** monitor I get an event when connecting and disconnecting the monitor via HDMI. But with a **Dell SE2216H** I get no event when disconnecting the monitor from the HDMI port.

**Note**: I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB OS.

Comment: Getting DisplaySettingsChanged would be more of an accident than intentional.  Surely you'll need to pay attention to plug&play notifications.  Google "wm_devicechange hdmi" for decent hits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hans Passant.
But WM_DISPLAYCHANGE also give the same issue. The HDMI monitor Arrival/Removal not invoked properly.same as I mentioned already...

Acer S240HL monitor getting Arrival Removal Events.But Dell SE2216H Monitor not getting removal event.it gets only arrival events.

But in Devcon utility give arrival/Removal properly for both monitors.Is there any way to get arrival/removal events using Devcon in C# WPF?

Comment: WM_DEVICECHANGE is a very different notification from WM_DISPLAYCHANGE.